# Will upgrading from 2.7.9 to 2.7.10 potentially break anything?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently running 2.7.9 but I'd like to upgrade to 2.7.10 due to a library only available there. I can run my code in staging as an integration test to try to catch any bugs caused by changing version, but I can't guarantee everything will get tested/seen immediately. Should I be concerned about anything breaking between these two versions?

Comment: Have you looked at the 2.7.10 [changelog](https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/15c95b7d81dc/Misc/NEWS)?

Comment: Yes, you should be concerned: it's not terribly *likely* that the upgrade will break anything, but it's always possible. Run your extensive unit test suite after the upgrade to make sure nothing breaks! (And if you don't *have* an extensive unit test suite, write one!)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, 2.7.10 is just a bug fix so it will only prevent things from breaking.  You can check out https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/ to get the release notes which are exceptionally brief.  Also if you go through the changelog you could look up your dependencies and see if any of them are affected: https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/15c95b7d81dc/Misc/NEWS

Comment: I think your definition of "exceptionally brief" is exceptional. :-) Looks like a good few hundred lines of changelog to me.

Comment: haha true, i just meant their description was `Python 2.7.10 is a bug fix release of the Python 2.7.x series.`

Comment: One would hope that were true. Certainly 2.7.11 introduced new bugs.

Comment: ya it's kind of a weird question though, because no one can really answer it truthfully without knowing his code and dependencies so my answer is probably a phallacy in that respect.  I'm probably right but possibly wrong and there's really no way to know.

Comment: Indeed. Very unlikely that upgrade would bring problems. But asker should just test.

Comment: ya I just figured I'd tell him what he wanted to hear.  If it does break anything I'd be interested to know what and why.  Probably the python developers would like to know too.